# Turning list-of-lists into set of lists in scheme for macro expansion body?

Tags: scheme

Is there a general way to take a list of items and flatten it to depth zero so that they can be spliced into a macro expansion? For instance:

```
((+ 1 2) (+ 3 4) (+ 4 5)) -> (+ 1 2) (+ 3 4) (+ 4 5)
```

Comment: How do want to "get" the result? One binding can't hold 3 different root objects...

Comment: Well in particular this is for use in a macro, I would ideally like to take the result of my macro and break it out into three top-level expressions...

Comment: If it's for a sequence of expressions from a macro, then you need to wrap them in a `begin`.  As for the flattening, you can do that with a `...` after the thing that you want to splice up.  This is assuming that you're using `syntax-rules` or `syntax-case`, of course.

Comment: Ah OK begins are what I was using, just was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: @EliBarzilay Since this seems to have worked for the user, you should post it as an answer.  (I'd upvote it, anyhow.) I think there are similar questions for Common Lisp, but I didn't find another for Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is based on Eli Barzilay's comment that never ended up getting turned into an answer.  That's why it's community wiki.*

If you want a sequence of expressions for the expansion of a macro, then you need to wrap them in a `begin`. As for the flattening, you can do that with a `...` after the thing that you want to splice up. This is assuming that you're using `syntax-rules` or `syntax-case`, of course.